# Extend existing protocols to implement another protocol with default implements

Tags: swift, protocols, protocol-extension

Is it possible to add protocol compliance to a different protocol by way of an extension?

For instance we would like A to comply with B:

```
protocol A {
  var a : UIView {get}
}

protocol B {
  var b : UIView {get}
}
```

I want to give a default implementation (compliance) of B to objects of type A

```
// This isn't possible
extension A : B {
  var b : UIView {
    return self.a
  }
}
```

The motivation being to reuse objects of A in cases where a B is required without creating my own "bridge"

```
class MyClass {
  func myFunc(object : A) {
    ...
    ...
    let view = object.a 
    ... do something with view ...

    myFunc(object)      // would like to use an 'A' without creating a 'B'
  }

  func myFunc2(object : B) {
    ...
    ...
    let view = object.b
    ... do something with view ...

  }
}
```

As a side note we can extend a class to implement a protocol

```
class C {
  let C : UIView
}

// this will work
extension C : B {
  var B : UIView {
    return self.c
  }
}
```

and protocols can give default implementations

```
extension A {
  // a default implementation
  var a : UIView {
     return UIView()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

When extending `A`, you could specify that the type also conforms to `B`:

```
extension A where Self: B {
    var b : UIView {
        return self.a
    }
}
```

Then make your type conform to `A` and `B`, e.g.

```
struct MyStruct : A, B {
    var a : UIView {
        return UIView()
    }
}
```

Due to the protocol extension, instances of `MyStruct` will be able to use `a` and `b`, even though only `a` was implemented in `MyStruct`:

```
let obj = MyStruct()
obj.a
obj.b
```

Comment: I've used the "where Self:B..." in the past but it still requires defining your "MyStruct". "MyStruct" is a "one use" bridge which entails boiler plate code. I'm looking for the most concise way , such that I don't have to create an intermediary construct to perform the mapping. Ideally I would be able to extend the protocol , in the way we can extend a class or a struct.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, in that case could you not combine using `where Self:B` and a protocol extension?

Comment: @ABakerSmith have you tried compile above code? I also tried this approach but the compiler still kept telling MyStruct doesn't conform to protocol B. My protocol B is from third party and written in Objective C.

Comment: @Flow, yes the code compiles for me. Are sure you're correctly implementing the requirements of your protocol `B` in the extension of `A`?

Comment: @ABakerSmith thanks for your reply. It did compile in my demo projects using pure Swift. However, I found, if protocol B is declare in Objective-C, the project won't compile. (That's unfortunately is my case, the protocol is from third party) I created a demo project here https://github.com/linktoming/Protocol-Demo the protocol C is in written in Objective-C in the demo.

Comment: @Flow, taking a look at the project it seems like the real problem is you can't mark the `c` method (from protocol `C`) with `@objc` in the extension of `A`. It might be worth posting a question on this topic.

Comment: @ABakerSmith ok, I posted a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040211/how-to-provide-default-implementation-of-an-objective-c-protocol-in-a-swift-prot), please feel free to modify it to describe the problem better.

Answer (score 5):

You can make `A` *inherits* from `B`:

```
protocol A: B { var a: String { get } }
protocol B    { var b: String { get } }

// Default implementation of property b
extension A {
    var b: String { get { return "PropertyB" } }
}


class MyClass: A {
    var a: String { get { return "PropertyA" } }

    func printA(obj: A) {
        print(obj.a)
        printB(obj)
    }

    func printB(obj: B) {
        print(obj.b)
    }
}

let obj = MyClass()
obj.printA(obj)
```

Since `A` inherits from `B`, every property in `B` is available in `A`.

Comment: This is fundamentally different than what the OP is asking.  If he doesn't have control of `A` or `B`, this won't be of much help.

Comment: Then I suppose you can make a protocol `C` that implements both `A` and `B`, with default implementations as needed?

Comment: I don't want to create extra protocols.

Comment: Then you are asking an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @CodeDifferent have you tried compile above code? I was trying the same approach but the compiler kept telling class A doesn't conform to protocol B in Swift 2.