# How to provide default Implementation of an Objective-C protocol in a Swift protocol extension

Tags: swift, swift2, swift-protocols

In my code, I'm referring a protocol written in Objective-C in another protocol written in Swift like this:

```
// Objective-C
@protocol C
- (void)c;
@end

//Swift    
protocol A {
  var a : UIView { get }
}

extension A where Self: C {
  var a : UIView {
    return UIView()
  }

  func c() {
    // default implementation of c
    // self.a bla bla bla
  }
}
// Compiler will complain ViewController does not conform to C
class ViewController: UIViewController, A, C {
  //...
}
```

The problem is even though I provided default implementation of C in the protocol A, the ViewController seems unable to get it and the code won't compile due to the `ViewController does not conform to C` error. It would be fine if the protocol C is written in Swift.

In my actual project, the protocol C is from third party (`GIDSignInDelegate`) which I cannot simply rewrite them. It's a common usage if you want to build some abstraction upon other abstractions written in Objective-C.

I created a sample project here: https://github.com/linktoming/Protocol-Demo

Comment: A related discussion is [Swift - extend existing protocols to implement another protocol with default implements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326309/swift-extend-existing-protocols-to-implement-another-protocol-with-default-imp/37353146?noredirect=1#comment63499993_37353146)

Comment: Swift protocol extensions are not available from Objective-C code. It seems to be inferring, in this case, that if the protocol was written from Objective-C, that it would be called from Objective-C, but it can't if the implementation is relying upon a default implementation in a Swift protocol extension.

Comment: Rather than implementing `A` as a protocol with an extension, you can implement it as a `UIViewController` subclass that conforms to `C`, and then have `ViewController` subclass from `A` instead of `UIViewController`.

Comment: @Rob right, that's one option. I used a similar approach of using a concrete class but using it as a member instead of parent class. I don't want to introduce non-VC related responsibility into VC.