# Swift 4 protocol composition conformance

Tags: swift, swift4

[*First of all if someone has a better name for the question, proposal are well accepted. I didn't find a better name for this question so far.*]

So, that's the question.

Assuming I have a protocol `ProtocolA`, a protocol `ProtocolB` and a protocol `ProtocolX` defined as following:

```
protocol ProtocolA {
  func doSomethingA()
}

protocol ProtocolB {
   func doSomethingB()
}

protocol ProtocolX {
   var handler: ProtocolA { get }
}
```

Then I have a proper implementation in a class of my ProtocolX as following:

```
class Donald: ProtocolX {
   ...
   var handler: ProtocolA { ... }
   ...
}
```

Then **everything is ok** and the protocol requirement is correctly fulfilled.

**BUT**

If I implement like that:

```
class Donald: ProtocolX {
   ...
   var handler: ProtocolA & ProtocolB
   ...
}
```

I have a compile-time issue reporting that my class `Donald` does not conform to `ProtocolX` (that, by specification, requires that the var `handler` must be conform to `ProtocolA`).

*Theoretically* the var `handler` IS conform to `ProtocolA` (but it's also conform to `ProtocolB`).

Then my question is: **Why the compile-time issue**? Swift limitation or conceptual issue on my side?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/42561685/2976878 – In short, there’s no real reason why it isn’t possible. The compiler just doesn’t handle it yet.

Comment: Thanks. I'll follow this question as well.

Comment: I dont see how it conforms... it is explicitly saying handler is something that conforms to A AND B

Comment: please read blog about protocols. https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0095-any-as-existential.md

Comment: This has already been reported as a bug: [SR-629](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-629?jql=text%20~%20%22protocol%22) but Apple said they wouldn't fix it. Protocol conformance has to be exact. I wonder what magic they pulled for `Codable = Encodable & Decodable` though

Comment: @CodeDifferent Where have Apple said that they won't fix it? As I understand it, this is something the Swift team want (progress tracked by https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-522).

Answer (score 1):

Theres no good reason why this shouldn't work, it just isn't supported by the compiler yet.

Currently, ProtocolX specifies that the handler must be of type `ProtocolA`, meaning that if you declare your class `Donald` with anything other than a `ProtocolA` type for the handler it will not fulfil the protocol's requirements.

You can however specify the handler as type `ProtocolA` but set it to a property of type `ProtocolA & ProtocolB`. In which case the property will be cast to `ProtocolA` and you will need to do an additional cast in order to use `ProtocolB`'s attributes. For example:

```
typealias ProtocolAB = ProtocolA & ProtocolB

class AB: ProtocolAB {
    func doSomethingA() {}
    func doSomethingB() {}
}

class Donald: ProtocolX {
    var handler: ProtocolA {
        return AB()
    }

    func f() {
        handler.doSomethingA() // is valid
        handler.doSomethingB() // is not valid without casting the handler as `ProtocolB`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably solve the issue by extending one of the protocols to implement the other one as well and that way you could workaround the issue.

You can make A inherits from B:

```
protocol ProtocolA: ProtocolB {
  func doSomethingA()
}

protocol ProtocolB {
   func doSomethingB()
}

protocol ProtocolX {
   var handler: ProtocolA { get }
}
```

Since A inherits from B, every property in B is available in A.

You could then use them both in protocol X as A inherits from b

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37326309/9497657)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the type specified in a protocol is, at least currently, required to be exact. There are some workarounds you can do at the present, however.

The simplest option is to just keep `handler` as `ProtocolA` but actually store a `ProtocolA & ProtocolB` object. This is doable as long as you don't need to conform to a protocol that also has `var handler: ProtocolB`.

```
class Donald: ProtocolX {
    var abHandler: ProtocolA & ProtocolB
    var handler: ProtocolA { return abHandler }
}
```

If you had a more complex situation where you actually *need* `handler` to be both `ProtocolA` and `ProtocolB`, you would have to use associated types in the protocols:

```
protocol ProtocolX {
    associatedtype Handler: ProtocolA
    var handler: Handler { get }
}
protocol ProtocolY {
    associatedtype Handler: ProtocolB
    var handler: Handler { get }
}
```

The problem with associated types is that you need a concrete type for them, so even though `ProtocolA & ProtocolB` is a valid type of variable, it cannot be used as the associated type `Handler`. So, you would either need to make a specific, concrete type to be the `Handler`:

```
struct PrintAB: ProtocolA, ProtocolB {
    func doSomethingA() { print("A") }
    func doSomethingB() { print("B") }
}
class Donald: ProtocolX, ProtocolY {
    var handler: PrintAB
}
```

…or you could make `Donald` itself generic:

```
class Donald<Handler>: ProtocolX, ProtocolY where Handler: ProtocolA & ProtocolB {
    init(handler: Handler) { self.handler = handler }
    var handler: Handler
}
```

While either of these would work, you would also lose the ability to use `ProtocolX` as the type of a variable, i.e. `let someX: ProtocolX = donald` would no longer work because of the associated type requirement in `ProtocolX`.

Of course if you can control the protocol definitions, you can avoid this situation by having different names for the handlers, reducing the problem to the simpler scenario:

```
class Donald: ProtocolX, ProtocolY {
    var abHandler: ProtocolA & ProtocolB
    var aHandler: ProtocolA { return abHandler } // renamed in ProtocolX
    var bHandler: ProtocolB { return abHandler } // renamed in ProtocolY
}
```